Calculating the maximum curvature of $y^{2}=2x^{3}-\frac{3}{2}x+0.5$
I was asked to calculate the maximum curvature of the following curve:
$y^{2}=2x^{3}-\frac{3}{2}x+0.5$
Using the implicet formula I got:
$\kappa\left(x,y\right)=\pm\frac{-48xy^{2}+72x^{4}-36x^{2}+\frac{9}{2}}{\left(36x^{4}+18x^{2}+\frac{9}{4}+4y^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$
Using parameterization of $\left(x(t),y(t)\right)=\left(cos(2t),cos(3t)\right),t\in\mathbb{R}$ I got:
$\kappa(t)=\frac{18\cdot sin(2t)\cdot cos(3t)-12sin(3t)\cdot cos(2t)}{\left(4sin^{2}(2t)+9sin^{2}(3t)\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$
now taking the derviative of $κ(t)$ and trying to find its maximum seemed way to hard, and trying to get an implicet function of x: $y=\pm\sqrt{2x^{3}-\frac{3}{2}x+0.5}$ and using the graph curvature formula:
$\kappa_{y}=\frac{y''(x)}{\left(1+\left(y'(x)^{2}\right)\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$
also seemed way to hard given that I calculated:
$\kappa'_{y}=\frac{\sqrt{\left(1+\left(y'(x)^{2}\right)\right)}\cdot\left(y'''(x)\cdot\left(1+\left(y'(x)^{2}\right)\right)-3\cdot y''^{2}(x)\cdot y'(x)\right)}{\left(1+\left(y'(x)^{2}\right)\right)^{3}}$
and $y'_{+}=\frac{12x^{2}-3}{4\sqrt{2x^{3}-\frac{3x}{2}+\frac{1}{2}}}\\y''_{+}=\frac{48x^{4}-72x^{2}+48x-9}{16\left(2x^{3}-\frac{3x}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\\y'''_{+}=-\frac{192x^{6}-720x^{4}+960x^{3}-540x^{2}+144x-15}{64\left(2x^{3}-\frac{3x}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\frac{5}{2}}}$
so subbing in to the result is also hard,
while subbing into the curvature of a graph before taking its derivative yields:
$\frac{\frac{48x^{4}-72x^{2}+48x-9}{16\left(2x^{3}-\frac{3x}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}}{\left(1+\left(\frac{12x^{2}-3}{4\sqrt{2x^{3}-\frac{3x}{2}+\frac{1}{2}}}\right)^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$
which is also really hard...
is there a way by looking at the curve that I can understand where is the maximum curvature?
the curve looks like this:

Any help would be apprecited!

Biggest curvature is at the smallest radius of curvature, I will say it is a the "corners", $x=0.5$

I wasn't taught that... Mind giving a source or explaining it?

One can be Wikipedia, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_curvature

You can simplify the curvature expression. It turns out that, after calculations like this one, the curvature is at $x=0.5$, due to the “corner” and at $x=\frac{2\sqrt{10}}9-\frac{23}{18}$, near the maximum.

@ТymaGaidash mind showing how can I simplify the expression? wolframalpha kept it the same...

@EDX I will try looking at that, thanks!

@Gardosh You can probably expand the square and combine the $\frac32$ powers to start. Plugging in an arbitrary constant in WA gives the curvature as $\frac{24x+36}{(36x^2+44x+17)^\frac32}$ which is equal to the curvature up to a sign.

Am I missing something when I plug in x=0.5 y is 0 and I get that the curvature is 0 then how can it be maximal there?

The curvature is maximal where visually the curve is most curved. Looking at your picture, it’s clearly when $x=0.5$. So the curvature can’t be zero there.

pluging x=0.5 and y=0 to here $\kappa\left(x,y\right)=\pm\frac{-48xy^{2}+72x^{4}-36x^{2}+\frac{9}{2}}{\left(36x^{4}+18x^{2}+\frac{9}{4}+4y^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$ gives 0

Can someone tell me if the curvature is even defined at the singularity $(1/2,0)$??? The implicit formula surely doesn't work, since the denominator is zero.

I rewrite the equation as $y^2 = 2 (x+1)(x-\frac12)^2$. This is a singular cubic, with a singularity at $(1/2,0)$, so it has a rational parametrization: taking $t = y/(x-\frac12)$ gives
$$ (x,y) = \Bigl( \frac{t^2}{2} - 1, \frac{t(t^2-3)}{2} \Bigr). $$
This has curvature
$$ \kappa(t) = \frac{|x'y'' - x''y'|}{({x'}^2+{y'}^2)^{3/2}}
= \frac{\tfrac32(t^2+1)}{(t^2+(\tfrac32(t^2-1))^2)^{3/2}} $$
which is maximized only when its logarithmic derivative is zero:
$$ 0 = \frac{\kappa'(t)}{\kappa(t)} = \frac{2t}{t^2 + 1} - \frac32 \frac{t(9t^2-7)}{t^2+(\tfrac32(t^2-1))^2}.$$
Clearing denominators gives $t$ times a quadratic polynomial in $t^2$, with real solutions
$$ t = 0, \pm \frac13 \sqrt{4 \sqrt{10} - 5}. $$
Now $t = 0$ (corresponding to $(x,y) = (-1,0)$) is a local minimum. The other two solutions are the global maxima, where $x = (4 \sqrt{10}-23)/18 \approx -0.575$, $y \approx \pm0.991$, and $\kappa \approx 3.247$. (The curvature approaches zero as $t \to \pm\infty$.)

The curvature of an implicit curve is not well-defined at a singularity, since the partial derivatives are zero so the formula for curvature has the indeterminate form $0/0$. But in this case the curvature does have a limit as we approach the singularity, which is at $t = \pm \sqrt{3}$ in the above parametrization. The limit is $\sqrt{3}/12 \approx 0.144$.

Using the change of variable $u=x-\frac12$ should simplify some of the calculations.

@MikhailKatz I don't think it helps - the constant term disappears from all the derivatives.

Thanks for the detailed answer!


Using the implicet formula I got:
$\kappa\left(x,y\right)=\pm\frac{-48xy^{2}+72x^{4}-36x^{2}+\frac{9}{2}}{\left(36x^{4}+18x^{2}+\frac{9}{4}+4y^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$

Using this for $F(x,y)=y^2-2x^3+\frac 32x-\frac 12$, I got
$$\begin{align}\kappa&=\frac{|F_y^2F_{xx}-2F_xF_yF_{xy}+F_x^2F_{yy}|}{(F_x^2+F_y^2)^{3/2}}
\\\\&=\frac{\bigg|(2y)^2(-12x)+(-6x^2+\frac 32)^2\times 2\bigg|}{\bigg((-6x^2+\frac 32)^2+(2y)^2\bigg)^{3/2}}
\\\\&=\frac{|-48xy^{2}+72x^{4}-36x^{2}+\frac{9}{2}|}{\left(36x^{4}\color{red}-18x^{2}+\frac{9}{4}+4y^{2}\right)^{3/2}}\end{align}$$
Using $y^2=2x^3-\frac 32x+\frac 12$, we have
$$\begin{align}\kappa&=\frac{\bigg|-48x(2x^3-\frac 32x+\frac 12)+72x^4-36x^2+\frac 92\bigg|}{(36x^4-18x^2+\frac 94+4(2x^3-\frac 32x+\frac 12))^{3/2}}
\\\\&=\frac{|-\frac 32(2 x - 1)^3 (2 x + 3)|}{(\frac 14(2 x - 1)^2 (36 x^2 + 44 x + 17))^{3/2}}\end{align}$$
So, the curvature is not defined at $(x,y)=(\frac 12,0)$.
For $x\not=\frac 12$, we have
$$\kappa=\frac{12|2 x + 3|}{(36x^2+44x + 17)^{3/2}}$$
with
$$\lim_{x\to\frac 12}\kappa=\frac{\sqrt 3}{12}\approx 0.1443$$
Let us consider
$$\kappa^2=\frac{144(2x+3)^2}{(36x^2+44x+17)^3}:=G(x)$$
We have
$$G'(x)= \frac{-1152 (2 x + 3) (36 x^2 + 92 x + 41)}{(36 x^2 + 44 x + 17)^4}$$
So, the maximum value of $G(x)$ is
$$\max\bigg(G\bigg(\frac{-23-4\sqrt{10}}{18}\bigg),G\bigg(\frac{-23+4\sqrt{10}}{18}\bigg)\bigg)=G\bigg(\frac{-23+4\sqrt{10}}{18}\bigg)=\frac{253+80\sqrt{10}}{48}$$
Therefore, the maximum curvature is $\color{red}{\sqrt{\frac{253+80\sqrt{10}}{48}}}\approx 3.247$ which is attained when $x=\frac{-23+4\sqrt{10}}{18}\approx -0.575$.

I think there is a mistake: we have $F_x=F_y=0$ at $(x,y)=(1/2,0)$, so the curvature formula is indeterminate like $0/0$. In fact we have $\lim_{x\to 1/2} \kappa = \sqrt3/12$ as in my answer.

I corrected my answer. Thanks.

I suggest you double check your calculations - computer assistance is helpful. Looks can be deceiving.

I didn't think about subbing $y^2$ for $2x^3+1.5x-0.5$ using that I could have solved it alone so I thank u for that

@Gardosh : Again I was wrong. Really sorry for the confusion. I corrected my answer with which WolframAlpha agrees.

It's fine I missed the fact that I can do that substitution and that I had a calculation error, so using both I can solve it my self which is what I wanted any ways, so thanks.

@Gardosh : You are welcome! Glad if my answer could help. It was not easy for me to notice that the substitution works either.
